# Does this set satisfy the definition of a subspace of $\mathbb R^3$

Tags: linear-algebra, elementary-set-theory

I am working through the questions of the Mathematics for Machine Learning book (Page 72 Q2.9 part d.) [Here](https://mml-book.github.io/book/mml-book.pdf)) and wanted to confirm where my understanding is incorrect as I am in disagreement with the official solution manual (Page 13/74 [Here](https://dokumen.pub/mathematics-for-machine-learning-mml-official-solutions-instructors-solution-manual-9781108455145-9781108470049-9781108569323-1108470041-1108569323-110845514x.html))

I fully accept that I am probably wrong in my understanding but I wanted to get the communities thoughts here to point out where I have gone wrong so I can bridge the gap in my understanding.

Question: Determine whether the set is a subspace of $\Bbb{R^3}$

$$D = \{ \boldsymbol{x^3} \in \Bbb{R^3} \ | \ x_2 \in \Bbb{Z} \}$$

The solution manual states that for the vector $(0,1,0)$ which when multiplied by $\pi$ means that the scalar multiplication of the vector is not within $D$ and hence is not closed under scalar multiplication and hence is not a subspace. I do agree with the idea that for that particular vector, this holds true.

However, my question is that for $x_2 = 0, \boldsymbol{x} \ \in \ \mathbb{Z}$, which could have a vector of the form $(x_1, 0, x_3) : x_1, x_3 \in \mathbb{R}$ does this then not satisfy the conditions for a subspace since i) it contains the zero vector, ii) it is closed under vector addition and iii) closed under scalar multiplication.

Am I not allowed to add further conditions to this set, i.e., by stating that $x_2 = 0$ to make this a subspace?

I would sincerely appreciate the communities thoughts here.

Comment: It sounds like you're asking: if you change the given set to a different set, namely $\{ (x_1,0,x_3)\colon x_1,x_3\in\Bbb R\}$, is the new set a subspace of $\Bbb R^3$? The answer is yes (and it's a good exercise for you to verify that). However, this fact has no bearing on the status of the original set, which is still not a subspace.

Comment: Thank you! If in an answer I were to state the conditions for this to be a subspace, namely iff $x_2 = 0$, would this in your view be correct or does this then become far too tedious in checking for all edge cases? The reason I asked is that the answer to the previous question in the book stated that for the subspace $C = { {x^3} \in \Bbb{R^3} \  | \ Ax = \gamma}, \gamma \in \Bbb{R}$, then if $A = (1, -2 , 3)$  this was a subspace iff $\gamma = 0$. The fact the authors provided a restriction on $\gamma$ made me think this was fine to do for elements of ${x^3}$